# jquery-ui slide left doesn't work first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When I'm using show() and hide() methods from jquery-ui:

```
var current = 1;
function slide(buttonNum) {
  if (current != buttonNum){
      $("#page" + current).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 800, function() {
        $("#page" + buttonNum).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800);
      });
      current = buttonNum;
    }
}
```

My intention is that every time button is clicked for this function the page would scroll left to change to required page.

The problem is that it doesn't work first time I'm clicking page number with function above(the current div would slide to the left, but div which I change to just pops up without animation) but works normally other times.

my css is as follows:

```
    .slider { 
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden; 
    }
    .slider .content { 
        position: relative; 

    }
    .slider .content .page { 
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        background-size: cover;

    }
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="content">
    <div id='page1' class="page">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </div>
    <div id='page2' class="page">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </div>
    <div id='page3' class="page">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<a onclick='slide(1)' href="#">1</a>
<a onclick='slide(2)' href='#'>2</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding the elements that you expect not to be visible at the beginning, so that the show animation will actually execute.  E.g. add this at the top:

```
$("#page2").hide();
$("#page3").hide();
```

That way running `.show()` on them will have an effect.